# How to Use OpenCV Convert BGR(cv::Mat) to NV12(cv::Mat)

Tags: c++, opencv

I know how to convert BGR to YV12 by `CV_BGR2YUV_YV12` option in OpenCV, but I am not able to find 2NV12 or 2NV21 standard.

Where can I find a example code?